# Agent is not connecting through JNLP (java 11 is installed on both master and agent)

Tags: jenkins, jnlp, agent, connection-timeout

Feb 17, 2023 10:06:16 AM org.jenkinsci.remoting.engine.WorkDirManager initializeWorkDir
INFO: Using /home/ubuntu/remoting as a remoting work directory
Feb 17, 2023 10:06:16 AM org.jenkinsci.remoting.engine.WorkDirManager setupLogging
INFO: Both error and output logs will be printed to /home/ubuntu/remoting
Feb 17, 2023 10:06:16 AM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main createEngine
INFO: Setting up agent: test
Feb 17, 2023 10:06:16 AM hudson.remoting.Engine startEngine
INFO: Using Remoting version: 3071.v7e9b_0dc08466
Feb 17, 2023 10:06:16 AM org.jenkinsci.remoting.engine.WorkDirManager initializeWorkDir
INFO: Using /home/ubuntu/remoting as a remoting work directory
Feb 17, 2023 10:08:27 AM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener error
SEVERE: Connection failed.
io.jenkins.remoting.shaded.jakarta.websocket.DeploymentException: Connection failed.
at io.jenkins.remoting.shaded.org.glassfish.tyrus.container.jdk.client.JdkClientContainer$1.call(JdkClientContainer.java:187)
at io.jenkins.remoting.shaded.org.glassfish.tyrus.container.jdk.client.JdkClientContainer$1.call(JdkClientContainer.java:107)
at io.jenkins.remoting.shaded.org.glassfish.tyrus.container.jdk.client.JdkClientContainer.openClientSocket(JdkClientContainer.java:192)
at io.jenkins.remoting.shaded.org.glassfish.tyrus.client.ClientManager$3$1.run(ClientManager.java:647)
at io.jenkins.remoting.shaded.org.glassfish.tyrus.client.ClientManager$3.run(ClientManager.java:696)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
at io.jenkins.remoting.shaded.org.glassfish.tyrus.client.ClientManager$SameThreadExecutorService.execute(ClientManager.java:849)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:118)
at io.jenkins.remoting.shaded.org.glassfish.tyrus.client.ClientManager.connectToServer(ClientManager.java:493)
at io.jenkins.remoting.shaded.org.glassfish.tyrus.client.ClientManager.connectToServer(ClientManager.java:337)
at hudson.remoting.Engine.runWebSocket(Engine.java:674)
at hudson.remoting.Engine.run(Engine.java:499)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out
at java.base/sun.nio.ch.UnixAsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
at java.base/sun.nio.ch.UnixAsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(UnixAsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.java:252)
at java.base/sun.nio.ch.UnixAsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.finish(UnixAsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.java:198)
at java.base/sun.nio.ch.UnixAsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.onEvent(UnixAsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.java:213)
at java.base/sun.nio.ch.EPollPort$EventHandlerTask.run(EPollPort.java:306)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)

Comment: check if the port and ip is added in firewall

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I'm using ec2 instance , enabled all the ports as i'm using for testing purpose and haven't blocked any IP address in NACL , but still facing the same . 
says connection failed/ connection timed out 

hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener error SEVERE: Connection failed.

Comment: Unable to add a agent to Jenkins master through JNLP
I'm using Linux OS in both VM's , java 11 open jdk is installed on both machines 
error says connection timeout / connection failed 
cross checked no firewall (ports/ip) is not blocking